# How to create spline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spline

I want to create spline in QGIS. I have tried to use Cad-tools - Create spline line\poligon but I can only draw it and can't save.
What is wrong I am doing?
Is there other way to create spline?

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS enable the **CAD Tools Extension/Plugin** and the are spline tools that can create 'pure' arcs and splines.

[image]

Plugins Repository
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cadtools/

Description of each CAD Tool Function
http://www.catais.org/qgis/cadtools/

Comment: That icon is grey no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to copy and paste the created spline/polyline onto another layer and save it that way.

The plugin ArcheoCAD could also help, that is supposed to be able to join up points with curved lines.

I normally use the freehand tool to do it freehand, if you are good with a mouse then it works well. The lines end up a bit untidy when you look at them close up. In a printout at 1/10 though I have not noticed this problem

Comment: The problem is that I can't copy It because when I want to end drawing and click the mouse spline doesn't save, I can't understand why.
Please, can you write more about how you makes splines. I am new in GIS, I am studying so I'll be very thankful for detail answer.

Comment: It's Ok, spline is created. I have used other version of QGIS.

Comment: Bable, You should probably turn your comment into an answer, add the version number to both your question and answer, and accept your own answer, to make this useful to other people with the sane issue.